# Apply Gamma correction in avconv or ffmpeg

Tags: debian, video, ffmpeg

I cannot adjust a video using `avconv` or `ffmpeg` with Gamma correction. I use Debian Jessie, so I first suspected that `avconv` was incomplete, so following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian), I built ffmpeg myself.

Using [this blog post](https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/adjusting-video-contrast-brightness-saturation-and-color-balance-with-ffmpeg/), I assumed the following filter would be fine (to apply a Gamma of 0.5):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mp=eq2=0.5:1:1:1:1:1:1:1 out.mp4
```

However, it just says

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1faf6a0] No such filter: 'mp'
Error opening filters!
```

Has the filter been renamed? How do I apply a Gamma correction? So I looked at [this documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) and it seems I should be using the `eq` filter instead. Try:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf eq=gamma=0.5 out.mp4
```

No success:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x23466a0] No such filter: 'eq'
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Show the full console readout including the banner.

Comment: The `mp` "mplayer" filters were removed from FFmpeg after better, more suitable filters were added.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by default several filters are missing because ffmpeg folks don't like the GPL license... So here is what I did step-by-step:

(1) install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install yasm nasm \
            build-essential automake autoconf \
            libtool pkg-config libcurl4-openssl-dev \
            intltool libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
            libnotify-dev libglib2.0-dev libevent-dev \
            checkinstall
```

(2) clone repository

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git
```

(3) compile with GPL enabled:

```
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --prefix=/usr
time make -j 8
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ffmpeg
sudo checkinstall
```

In the last step you are asked to enter package information. I added the version information, but that should be optional.

---

Then it works:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "eq=gamma=0.5" out.mp4
```

---

**Edit**: Unfortunately the above gives you still a vanilla ffmpeg without any useful codec such as libx264. After spending hours on this, I concluded that the only way to make it work is forget about compiling from source, and adding deb-multimedia as is suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: An easier method is to simply [download a compiled binary of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Comment: never set /usr as a place to dump your builds, you'll probably break something and end up rebuilding your system. in your configure you should have specified more flags like --enable-nonfree, etc configure -help is your friend

Comment: GPL works this way, but I was then missing many other functionalities. FFmpeg needs a lot of `--enable-...` flags to match what is commonly distributed in e.g. Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly build ffmpeg from the git repo with 30+ libs and these work for me, as the ffmpeg documentation for examples is terrible

simple way, look up one of the default curves

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -codec:v blahblahblah -filter:v curves=preset=strong_contrast -codec:a copy dump_file.mp4
```

use the lut

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -codec:v blahblahblah -filter:v lutyuv=y=val*1.3 -codec:a copy dump_file.mp4
```

go balls out and define all min/max for rgb, this will lighten

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -codec:v blahblahblah -filter:v colorlevels=rimin=0.039:gimin=0.039:bimin=0.039:rimax=0.95:gimax=0.94:bimax=0.93 -codec:a copy dump_file.mp4
```

I confirmed with ffplay command still works with

```
ffplay movie.mp4 -vf eq=gamma=1.5
```