# How do I install ffmpeg on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, ffmpeg, libav

My installation of Debian Jessie is seemingly doing everything it can to prevent me from installing ffmpeg.

I have read [How to install FFmpeg on Debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian), but avconv is not an option and adding `deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free` to my sources.list didn't really help. I did `apt-get install libav-tools`, thinking it would get rid of ffmpeg's dependency problems.

Here's what trying to install ffmpeg gets me now:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice56 (>= 10:2.6.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter5 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
          Depends: libavformat56 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
          Depends: libavresample2 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
          Depends: libavutil54 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpostproc53 (>= 10:2.6.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libswresample1 (>= 10:2.6.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libswscale3 (>= 10:2.6.8) but 6:11.6-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is apt-get trying to tell me and how do I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `aptitude` to install it because it will give you possible solutions. Just make sure you look over each one carefully.

```
sudo aptitude install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 24):

It is now available for Jessy as a backport: https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/ffmpeg

Add something like this to /etc/apt/sources.list (with your preferred mirror):

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: From GAD3R's answer, you might also need:

`deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free` and `apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring` to get over the `NO_PUBKEY 5C808C2B65558117` APT error.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get `W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 78.129.164.123 80]`

Comment: @JonasJohansson: "Please keep in mind that backports doesn't follow LTS. Which means that we will drop support for oldstable (stretch) around one year after the release of buster. Thats in sync with the - official - security support for oldstable" (https://backports.debian.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Fix broken package

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Add the following lines to  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
deb-src http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
```

Update:

```
apt-get update
```

Add the key

```
apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
```

update

```
apt-get update
```

Remove `ffmpeg` Debian packge

```
apt-get remove ffmpeg
```

As root Install library packages and build tools:

```
apt-get install build-essential libmp3lame-dev libvorbis-dev libtheora-dev libspeex-dev yasm pkg-config libfaac-dev libopenjpeg-dev libx264-dev
```

Download the latest  ffmpeg from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#repositories)

```
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.0.2.tar.bz2
```

Extract it

```
tar xvjf ffmpeg-3.0.2.tar.bz2
```

Move into the  directory

```
cd ffmpeg-3.0.2
```

Configure, build and install:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
make -j 16
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 3):

Why no one use original debian recommendation ?? It is simple !

Just add

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free
```

to

> /etc/apt/sources.list

and run update:

> apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg && ffmpeg -i

```
ffmpeg -i
ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-vaapi --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of other answers.

Comment: it doesn't work for Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to [download an already compiled executable of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Once you download and extract it you have several options to run it:

- Navigate to the directory containing the executable and run `./ffmpeg -i ...` (note the `./` prefix).
- Provide the full path to the executable, such as `/home/user/Downloads/ffmpeg -i ...`
- Place it somewhere in your `PATH`, such as `~/bin`. Then run `source ~/.profile` or simply log out then log in. Now you can just run the `ffmpeg` command from anywhere without needing to use the two previous methods.

The downloadable executable is compiled daily and is always more up-to-date the what is available in the repository.